# Uploading file in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to upload a file to my application by following the instructions in the documentation of Symfony [Using the id as the filename](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/blob/2.7/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.rst#using-the-id-as-the-filename). But nothing happens when there is a previously uploaded file.

My form contains a field `File` only, which is associated with the entity`Document` as described in [Basic Setup](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/blob/2.7/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.rst#basic-setup), with the only difference that do not define the `$name` property.

My entity definition:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Document
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * @Assert\File()
     */
    private $file;
}
```

My form definition (within sonata admin class):

```
/**
 * @param FormMapper $formMapper
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper->add('file');
}
```

**When the document is new, the file is uploaded correctly.** ***But then if I try to upload another to replace the previous file then it does nothing and the old file still exists.***

The critical zone it's ([Using the id as the filename](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/blob/2.7/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.rst#using-the-id-as-the-filename)):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

// ...
class Document
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        // check if we have an old image path
        if (is_file($this->getAbsolutePath())) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->temp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            $this->path = 'initial';
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

The second time, when I try to change the previously uploaded file, these methods are not executed ([Using the id as the filename](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/blob/2.7/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.rst#using-the-id-as-the-filename)):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Document
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            $this->path = $this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->temp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->temp = null;
        }

        // you must throw an exception here if the file cannot be moved
        // so that the entity is not persisted to the database
        // which the UploadedFile move() method does
        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->id.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension()
        );

        $this->setFile(null);
    }
}
```

Anyone can tell me that I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please post some code where you are stuck. It will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Have a look at this bundle, it adds all the listeners etc for you: https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error described ("But nothing happens when there is a previously uploaded file.") suggest that this is a directory permission issue that prevents overriding an existing file.

In any case, the article you mentioned was recently declared obsolete and replaced by this other article: [How to Upload Files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html). Maybe reading this new article can help you spot the problem.

Comment: the issue is related with PreUpdate event, it is not triggered.

Comment: I use the Sonata project and not wanted to create a controller only to upload each file, so use Doctrine events (PrePersist,PreUpdate) within the entity itself ([Using Lifecycle Callbacks](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/blob/2.7/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.rst#using-lifecycle-callbacks)).